# Scala: why mutable Map and immutable Map have different result on same custom class instance as key?

Tags: scala, dictionary

My Scala version is `2.11.8` and Java version is `1.8.0_77`.

I had a custom class `V` extends `Ordered[V]`. I defined custom `compare` and `equals`. I want `V` instances have `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=` operators and can be thought equal when some specific attribute of them are equal.

Here is the simplified code extracted from my project:

```
class V(val value: Int, val score: Int = 0) extends Ordered[V] {
  def compare(that: V): Int = this.score compare that.score

  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = that match {
    case that: V => this.value == that.value
    case _ => false
  }
}

val a = new V(1, 2)
val b = new V(1, 3)

// return true because a.value == b.value
a == b
```

And strangely:

```
import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

val mm = collection.mutable.Map(a -> ArrayBuffer(0, 1), b -> ArrayBuffer(2, 3, 4))
val im = collection.immutable.Map(a -> ArrayBuffer(0, 1), b -> ArrayBuffer(2, 3, 4))

// return scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer()
mm.getOrElse(new V(1, 0), ArrayBuffer())

// return scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(2, 3, 4)
im.getOrElse(new V(1, 0), ArrayBuffer())
```

Why the result of `immutable.Map` and `mutable.Map` are different?

But when I define `hashCode` for `V`:

```
class V(val value: Int, val score: Int = 0) extends Ordered[V] {
  def compare(that: V): Int = this.score compare that.score

  override def hashCode: Int = value // new method here!

  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = that match {
    case that: V => this.value == that.value
    case _ => false
  }
}

val a = new V(1, 2)
val b = new V(1, 3)

a == b // true
```

And this time, the result are the same:

```
val mm = collection.mutable.Map(a -> ArrayBuffer(0, 1), b -> ArrayBuffer(2, 3, 4))
val im = collection.immutable.Map(a -> ArrayBuffer(0, 1), b -> ArrayBuffer(2, 3, 4))

// both return scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(2, 3, 4)
mm.getOrElse(new V(1, 0), ArrayBuffer())
im.getOrElse(new V(1, 0), ArrayBuffer())
```

Why does `hashCode` definition affect the result of mutable Map on custom class instance as key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does `hashCode` definition affect the result of mutable Map on
>   custom class instance as key

`immutable.Map` has a custom implementation up to 4 key value pairs (`Map1`, ...., `Map4`). The `get` operation for those customized implementations doesn't use an internal bucket array for hashcodes which maps to an object arrays where the values are actually stored, it simply stores key-value pairs as fields.

For example, here is `Map1.get` which is invoked by `getOrElse`:

```
class Map1[A, +B](key1: A, value1: B) extends AbstractMap[A, B] 
                                      with Map[A, B] with Serializable {
    def get(key: A): Option[B] =
      if (key == key1) Some(value1) else None
```

On the contrary, `mutable.Map` is a backed by a `mutable.HashMap` which uses a bucket to find the objects hashcode, which in turn point to the values in the object array. The objects inside those buckets are stored by their hashcode. Since your object doesn't implement a custom hashcode method, it derives it's hashcode from `Any` (`Object`). Thus, the mutable map *isn't* able to find the value inside those buckets, as equal values in your custom implementation don't have equal hashcodes.

Once you implement a custom hashcode method, and it obeys the rule that all equal instances should yield the same hashcode, `HashMap` is able to find the right bucket where your object is stored and invoke `equals` on the two objects, to see they're equal.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks! Some new questions, based on the implementation of `Map1`'s `get`, I guessed `immutable.Map` uses a collection of `Map1` (or `Map2`, `Map3`, `Map4`) instances to store our key-value? One `Map1`(or `Map2`, `Map3`, `Map4`) instance one key-value? When we lookup some key in an immutable Map, `immutable.Map` iterate the whole inner collection to find the corresponding value? Excuse me, I read the source code of `immutable.Map`, but I didn't find how do it process or do I have any misunderstanding?

Comment: @user3295962 `Map1` to `Map4` will be used depending on the number of arguments you pass to it's apply method (i.e., when you do Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2), you'll get a `Map2`). Regarding `immutable.Map`, it will definitely not iterate the entire collection. The whole meaning of a `Map` is that it should deliver constant time lookup of values based on their key.